Explanation of Lemma 12.19 in Jech's Set Theory
From chapter 12 of Jech's Set Theory:

Lemma 12.9. If $M$ is a transitive class and $\varphi$ is a $\Delta_0$-formula, then for all $x_1, \ldots, x_n$,
$$
\varphi^M(x_1, \ldots, x_n) \iff \varphi(x_1, \ldots, x_n).
$$
If (12.18) holds, we say that the formula $\varphi$ is absolute for the transitive model $M$.

Perhaps this is a silly question, but I was wondering what the meaning of the RHS in the above equivalence is.

It holds in $V$. Or, if you will, if $M$ is definable by a formula, you can convert the whole thing into a sentence and then we're saying that ZF proves the equivalence.

@AsafKaragila I'm sorry, but I continue just as lost. $V$ is the universal set, and I'm not sure of what it would mean to say it is a model without any other definition backing up the concept of $V$. On the other hand, if $M$ is definable by a formula, what is the "whole thing" that can be converted into a sentence?

It's just $\varphi$ itself, with no modifications.
For every $n$-ary formula $\varphi(x_1,...,x_n)$ we have an associated $n+1$-ary formula $\varphi^r(x_1,...,x_n,y)$ whose intuitive meaning is "$\varphi(x_1,...,x_n)$ holds inside $y$." My "$\varphi^r(...,y)$" is your text's "$\varphi^y$." In detail, $\varphi^r$ is gotten from $\varphi$ by replacing each $\forall v$ (resp. $\forall v\in w$) with $\forall v\in y$ (resp. $\forall v\in y\cap w$), and similarly for the existential quantifiers; of course even those are abbreviations, but I'm assuming you're already familiar with bounded variables in set theory.
The point is that if $\varphi$ happens to be a $\Delta_0$ formula, then $\mathsf{ZF}$ proves the following sentence: $$\forall y(\mathsf{Transitive}(y)\implies \forall x_1\in y,...,\forall x_n\in y(\varphi^r(x_1,...,x_n,y)\iff\varphi(x_1,...,x_n))$$ (modulo obvious abbreviations). For example, $\mathsf{ZF}$ proves that for every transitive set $y$ and every pair of sets $x_1,x_2\in y$ we have $\exists z\in x_2(x_1\in z)\iff \exists z\in y\cap x_2(x_1\in z)$; the right hand side of this biimplication is exactly the "$r$-version" of the left hand side.
Now the above is stated "schematically," i.e. one $\mathsf{ZF}$-theorem per $\Delta_0$-formula. However, we can in fact prove an "all-at-once" version of the theorem with a bit more care, using Godel numbering to quantify over $\Delta_0$ formulas and whipping up a truth predicate for $\Delta_0$ formulas; this all-at-once result is what the lemma as written states.

Sorry, but I'm struggling to grasp what $\phi(x_1,\ldots,x_n,y)$ could be. Is it just $\phi$, yet with all its bounded variables restricted to $y$?

@Sam Yes or almost, depending on exactly what you mean by restricting bounded variables. See the second half of the first main paragraph: "In detail, $\varphi^r$ is gotten from $\varphi$ by replacing each $\forall v$ (resp. $\forall v\in w$) with $\forall v\in y$ (resp. $\forall v\in y\cap w$), and similarly for the existential quantifiers." (And further on in the answer, in the sentence starting "for example," I give a worked example of this where $\varphi(x_1,x_2)\equiv \exists z\in x_2(x_1\in z)$.)
